# Getting error "ValueError: could not covert string to float " in integer sequence learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to machine learning and I am trying to develop a simple RNN for an integer sequence model ([Integer Sequence Learning - Kaggle Competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/integer-sequence-learning))

My dataset is taken from the Kaggle competition and following is my code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, window_size=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-window_size-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+window_size), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + window_size, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

# loading data
dataframe = pd.read_csv('G:/Python/integer_sequencing/train.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python', skipfooter=3)

dataset = dataframe.values
#dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67) #67 per cent used for training
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size # remaining used for testing
train, test = dataset[0:train_size], dataset[train_size:len(dataset)]
#print(train_data.head(n=10))

# normalize the datasets
scaler_train = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_test = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
train = scaler_train.fit_transform(train)
test = scaler_test.fit_transform(test)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

print(trainX.shape)
print(trainY.shape)
```

I get an error as follows:
[image]

How do I fix it? Please help...

PS - I am using [Time series prediction](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) as example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're feeding your network a `string` sequence. Double check the `dtype` of your input data and be absolutely sure that its a numpy array with `float` numbers inside it.

Comment: The dataset that I am using is the one that is provided in the Kaggle competition. The problem is to predict the next number in any integer sequence. The training data consists of all possible integer sequence.

Comment: I understand, but your input data shouldn't be `string` type otherwise this error will persist. Try splitting the sequence and converting each string number to a `float`.

Comment: Glad it helped, if you don't mind could you please accept my answer?